# Cocoapods not updating Flutter pod correctly

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I'm working on upgrading an app from Flutter 1.x to Flutter 2.x. When I ran `pod outdated' in the ios folder I get [this as the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaHjU.png):

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`
Analyzing dependencies
The color indicates what happens when you run `pod update`
<green>  - Will be updated to the newest version
<blue>   - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of specified version in Podfile
<red>    - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile

The following pod updates are available:
- Flutter 1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (latest version 2.0.2)
- Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 8.5.0 -> 8.5.0 (latest version 8.7.0)
- GoogleSignIn 5.0.2 -> 5.0.2 (latest version 6.0.0)
- PromisesObjC 1.2.12 -> 1.2.12 (latest version 2.0.0)
```

Because the numbers are red, that would mean that I have a specified version in the Podfile however after checking the file I have no such specification. Here is what I have in my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'PromisesObjC'

  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried running `pod deintegrate` and `pod cache clean --all` and neither have allowed it to update.

Has anyone else had this issue when updating a Flutter 1.x app to Flutter 2.x? I'm new to developing iOS applications with Flutter so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to delete the ```Podfile.lock``` ?

Comment: @EncryptedSpirit Yes I have tried that, it had no discernible affect.